# Find all Affine Transformations that map the given pyramid back to itself

Tags: euclidean-geometry, transformation, affine-geometry

I hope this question hasnt been posted before.

Let A(3, 2, 3), B(5, 2, 3), C(3, 5, 3) and D(6, 5, 5) be a pyramid. Find all affine transformations that map the pyramid back to itself.

So find all affine transformations *t* so that for each *x* in the pyramid *t(x)* also lies in the pyramid.

What is the strategy when solving these kind of tasks. You dont have to give me the solution, just a hint would be nice :) thank you

I have written the pyramid as P = A + t1*(B-A)+t2*(C-A)+t3*(D-A) and
I know that every affine transformation can be written as *t(x) = Mx + s*, where M is a semilinear matrix and *s* a vector. But that does not help a lot.

Comment: I assume the mapping is also surjective and there are no restrictions on the matrix. Then a hint is that there are 24 such transformations.